# Saving a .jpg to byte[] android

Tags: java, android, byte, apache-commons, parse-platform

This shouldn't be that hard, but I cannot figure this out. I need to save an image, on my end only, and build it dynamically so all my users will view these images. The tutorials on [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-saving) are very helpful, but not in the case of images. I need detailed explanations or helpful links. Thanks for looking.

This is all I have so far as far as saving an image. I am properly getting the file in my Data Browser, but if I try to view it, it only shows my string `"beatdown.jpg"` not the actual jpg.

```
....

private void saveImage() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

InputStream header = new FileInputStream("beatdown.jpg");   
byte[] head = IOUtils.toByteArray(header);

ParseFile file = new ParseFile(head);
try{
    file.save();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ParseObject displayImage = new ParseObject("displayImage");
displayImage.put("header", file);
try{
    displayImage.save();
} catch (ParseException e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I understand I am trying to get the string of "beatdown.jpg" to bytes in the code above, and it is not handling it as a `.jpg`. But I don't know how to make it a `.jpg`.

**EDIT:** I added [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). But when I run the code (see the above updated code), it won't register on anything on parse.com. I am getting this in my logcat;

`Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2498 that was originally bound here`

Comment: can you save it as a .jpg, turning the byte[] to a bitmap then compress to .jpg?

Comment: byte[] data = "beatdown.jpg".getBytes(); is creating bytes out of the string "beatdown.jpg", and not actually saving any image named beatdown.jpg. You need to use File to get the contents of the file.

Comment: Ok, I figured that is what I was doing. But I don't understand how to use file to get the contents? I researching it but not figuring it out. Do you have an example or a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key elements are:

```
File f = new File("pathToFile");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
byte[] bytes = new byte[f.length()];
fis.read(bytes);
```

Of course there's exception handling and the like to do, but this should be enough to give you the general idea.